# how to acquire list of notification area icons?

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar

i'm attempting to get code to list of all icons visible in the notification area, to the left of the time. i've been experimenting with `EnumDesktopWindows` and `GetWindowLong`, without finding any way to single out the system tray icons. thanks!

Comment: It seems unlikely that there is a way to achieve this. What are you trying to actually do? Maybe there is a different way.

Comment: This is most likely very different depending on the version of Windows...

Comment: This question needs some clarification. Do you need the "icon images", "references to be able to communicate messages to applications in system tray", "are you building a replacement for systray", etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use the accessibility interfaces to enumerate the children of `User Promoted Notification Area`.

Comment: Spy++ shows that the User Promoted Notification Area doesn't have children window. Can you please comment? (I think it may be an excellent article in 'the old new thing' - but a quick comment here will do).

Comment: Not child windows. Accessible children.